# Is it possible to even parse this as JSON in node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

So I'm trying to parse a wee little API which returns somewhat invalid JSON. I've been trying to do something like this:

```
    var request = require('request'),
        url = 'urlhere';
    request({
        url: url
    }, function(error, response, body) {
       if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
           var jsonData = JSON.parse(body),
               jsonArray = []; // For jsonArray.push later
           for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++)
               console.log(jsonData[i].name);
           jsonData.length = 0; // Clear array.
       }
    });
```

but the service I'm trying to read from has something similar to this as a return statement:

```
{
    people: [
        {
            name: "test"
        },
        {
            name: "test2"
        },
        {
            name: "test3"
        },
        {
            name: "test4"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've been trying to get this to work, but when I do it just returns [object Object]. When I went deeper, I found out that this isn't even valid JSON, or what websites and clients see it to be invalid JSON. Is there a way I can get around this in `node.js`?

Comment: That's not JSON but a regular object declaration. Looks like that API expects you to use `eval()` (you probably shouldn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not able to fix the incorrect JSON, I think the easiest would be to try and repair it by adding missing quotes for keys by using a regular expression:

search: `/(['"])?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(['"])?:/g`

replace: `"$&":`

Comment: For JS you could do this:
`var data = '{people: [{name: "test"}]}';
var json = data.replace(/(['"])?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(['"])?:/g, '"$2": ');`
I assume you can use that for Node as well

Comment: This worked, actually. I'm weirdly suprised. I don't know why it worked but it did.

Comment: Try to print the `json` variable. If you want to play around with regular expressions you could try: https://regex101.com/ or http://regexr.com/